# Coda file navigation with keyboard

Tags: coda

Is there any way to navigate files in Coda using the keyboard?  I love most things about Coda, but having to use the mouse to find and open files is a bit of a pain.  Hopefully I'm missing something obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you really want is SwitchFocus: http://habitatus.net/blog/2009/08/switch-focus-coda-plugin/

There are a couple of caveats. Make sure you read the comments that other people have submitted; they are helpful in getting you reasonable behavior in the sidebar file browser.

Comment: This is great, thanks.  Do you have any idea how to change the keystroke to open files?  They have cmd+down set as the default file open shortcut but I use cmd+arrows for spaces and would prefer not to have to unlearn that.  I looked through the source and couldn't figure out how to make that change.

Comment: I don't know how to modify those keyboard shortcuts; I had to get used to them too... but it's better than not having them. I think the guiding principle for Coda was to copy the behavior in the Finder (not saying that it's wrong or right...just saying I think that's why it's that way). If you're desperate you can download the code and try to implement it yourself (I have absolutely no idea how to start that…)

Answer (score 0):

`mount -t coda ...`, and then use your favorite shell/file manager?